# Images In CSS Integrity Issue

Tags: html, css, django

How do I link a local image in CSS as background-image? When I go to my localhost and console there is an error which says:

*"
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/base.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'VamhLHC0Rd5RsK5ayIQbhNx167AvkjG9xrdEDZaSFoc='. The resource has been blocked.
".*

I am using Django Framework.
How do I fix this?

This is my first question, so sorry if it is hard to understand.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried and is not working

Comment: Here is the code:
"""
main {
    background-image: '../images/background-image.jpeg';
}
""" -- Thanks @Iain Shelvington

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add a background image:

background
{background img: url("")

}

inside the quotes put in the link of the image you would like to use, hope this answered your question. if not please add a comment and specify a bit better. thx.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, but the error is still:
*"
ailed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/base.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'Unyu7PVOd9qQlGhyDrAd3PnsgT7AsJ24nJFeixWbOwo='. The resource has been blocked"*
Thanks.